# How to you tie different batch commands into one file to run sequentially

Tags: batch-file

I have a 5 batch files but I want to put them all in one file to run one after the other consecutively. Is that possible? What is the command that can tie the different files together .. I don't want 5 separate files.. But just one batch file with all the files in it running one after the other.

Comment: Call them with `start /wait`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider you have three batch files

**aaa.bat**

**bbb.bat**

**ccc.bat**

you can create separate batch file ddd.bat and the content of the file should be like

```
call aaa.bat
call bbb.bat
call ccc.bat
```

This will run multiple batch file in a sequence way

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want 5 separate files.. But just one batch file ...

It's not clear what you mean by this. 
If you want to have ***one batch file*** that does the functions of the five existing files,
you can probably just concatenate them with

```
copy aaa.bat+bbb.bat+ccc.bat+ddd.bat+eee.bat alphabet_soup.bat
```

and then check the combined file for things like the scripts

- using the same variable names (especially if `eee.bat` expects `%foo%` to be blank when it starts)
- having identical labels (e.g., `:foo`)
- doing `setlocal` without doing `endlocal`
- using end of file as a subroutine return
- using `exit` when they're done (you'll want to change that to `goto` the next script)

Comment: check the combined file for `GOTO:eof` as well, whether transfers control to the end of the current batch file, but reserve those `GOTO:eof` transfering control to the end of the current subroutine